# Извлечь цену вариативного товара в корзине

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, корзина

Сайт на wordpress woocommerce, из корзины нужно сделать кнопку оформления рассрочки и передать post запросом содержимое корзины и цены.

```
<input name="itemName_0" value="Apple iPhone 7 256 GB Onyx" type="hidden"/>
<input name="itemQuantity_0" value="1" type="hidden"/>
<input name="itemPrice_0" value="59000.00" type="hidden"/> 
<input name="itemName_1" value="Apple iPhone 6 64 GB Onyx" type="hidden"/>
...
```

Реализовал так (не знаю насколько правильно, главное работает):

```
<?php
    global $woocommerce;
    $items = $woocommerce->cart->get_cart();

        $mycount = 0;
        foreach($items as $item => $values) { 
            $_product =  wc_get_product( $values['data']->get_id()); 
            $tovar=$_product->get_title();
            $kolvo=$values['quantity'];
            $cena = get_post_meta($values['product_id'] , '_price', true);
            echo "<input name=itemName_$mycount value='$tovar' type=hidden>"; 
            echo "<input name=itemQuantity_$mycount value='$kolvo' type=hidden>"; 
            echo "<input name=itemPrice_$mycount value='$cena' type=hidden>"; 
            $mycount += 1;
            }
            ?>
```

Теперь вопрос. На сайте есть вариативные товары, как передавать цену именно выбранной вариации из корзины в моем случае?

Comment: Я боюсь покупать вариативные товары.

Comment: вы не покупаете на алиэкспрес?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

задал условия if else для простого и вариативного товара и все получилось

цену взял так: `cena=jQuery('form.cart span.woocommerce-Price-amount.amount').html().split('<')[0].replace(' ', '');`